# Why is there a pickup insurgent on ps3

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

So, it's been going around that GTA V online on the PS3 will no longer receive updates. I'm starting to question that because there's a Humane Labs heist with Lester that unlocks the pickup insurgent after the finale.

I thought the pickup insurgent was a part of the gunrunning update for PS4, Xbox One, and PC. Was that update also on the PS3?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can get it is because the [Humane Labs Heist](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/The_Humane_Labs_Raid) is part of the ["Heists Update"](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Heists_Update) from back in March 2015. This also included the Insurgent as an acquirable vehicle.

Gunrunning is not at all apart of that Heist, nor the vehicle.